# Changing Google Maps marker label color

Tags: javascript, angular-google-maps

I am unable to change color of a marker label, can any one kindly help me out with this?

```
for (i = 0; i < scope.dcDetails.packageProviders.length; i++) {
    scope.markerArray.push({
        id: scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].id,
        entityAddress: scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].entityAddress,
        pinCode: scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].pinCode,
        coords: {
            latitude: scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].latitude,
            longitude: scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].longitude,
        },
        name: scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].entityName,
        options:
            {
                labelClass: 'marker_labels',
                labelAnchor: '12 60',
                labelContent: scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].entityName
            }
    });
    scope.windowOptions[scope.dcDetails.packageProviders[i].id] = {
        visible: false,
    }
}
```